# Записать значения из this.props в this.state перед рендером компонента React

Tags: reactjs

Подскажите как правильно записать значения в this.state из this.props перед рендером компонента, пробегаю this.props в for in и записываю их в this.state чтобы при рендере данные из this.props отобразились в компоненте, все работает но выдает в консоли warning Uncontrolled Components ссылку на доки не кидайте, уже смотрел.

```
constructor(props) {
super(props); 
this.state = {
 name: '',
  surname: '',
  email: '',
  phone: ''
  }
 }

componentDidMount() {
    for(let key in this.props){
     if(this.props[key] != this.state[key]){
         this.setState({[key]: this.props[key]});
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: в конструкторе это сделай

Comment: да и зачем в цикле состояние обновлять? соберите полностью объект и полностью смените состояние...

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, вам здесь не нужен `componentDidMount`, все это можно инициализировать в конструкторе довольно элементарно:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        name: '',
        surname: '',
        email: '',
        phone: '',
        ...props
    }
}
```

Во-вторых, вам не мешает предусмотреть случай изменения свойств из вне в `componentWillReceiveProps`

```js
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const props = {};

    for (let key in nextProps) {
        if (nextProps[key] != this.state[key]) {
            props[key] = nextProps[key];
    }

    this.setState(props);
}
```

В-третьих, не понятно зачем хранить одни и те же данные в двух местах, чем вас `props` не устраивает? Помещая данные в `state` вы их а) дублируете, б) потенциально заставляете компонент перерисовываться дважды (в случае изменения свойств)